# Compiler complaining about wrong Data Type

Tags: vba, excel

I have written folowing procedure, each time I try to run it compiled says that `Data` is a wrong data type. `ChooseLineItem` takes a range as a parameter, and as you can see if `Data` is not a range then `ChooseLineItem` will not be executed.

So my question is how do I get this code to compile?

```
Public Function MakeKeyValPairs(Data As Variant) As Variant()
    Dim LineItem As Integer
    Dim Headers As KeyValStruct

    If TypeName(Data) = "Range" Then
        LineItem = ChooseLineItem(Data)
    Else
        LineItem = 1
    End If
    Headers = FindHeaders(Data)

    MakeKeyValPairs = AssembleAray(Data, Headers, LineItem)
End Function
```

FYI The reason why `Data` is decared as a variant is because it has to be able to accept ranges and arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Public Function MakeKeyValPairs(Data As Variant) As Variant()
        Dim LineItem As Integer, Headers As KeyValStruct, r as Range

        If TypeName(Data) = "Range" Then
        Set r = Data
        LineItem = ChooseLineItem(r)
    Else
        LineItem = 1
    End If
    Headers = FindHeaders(Data)

    MakeKeyValPairs = AssembleAray(Data, Headers, LineItem)
End Function
```

Comment: Looks like that worked, Thanks! I just have to wait untill Stack Overflow lets me accept the answer. In the mean while a silly question there is no way that `r` Range to somehow overwrite data in my spreadsheet? Assuming that my codes stays as you proposed.

Comment: No problem. No the **r** variable is just a reference to your Data variant. Therefore nothing should mess up / overwrite your data. The problem is just a compile issue not a run-time issue